# flutter error : add home text and image on page

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I want to add Text and image together on home.

However, the error continues to occur.
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: try to add your code

Comment: there is no property named child in scaffold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using wrong widget, replace your body with this:

```
body: Column(
  children: [
     const Text('닮은 꼴 찾기'),
     Image.asset('assets/images/face_home_img_1.png'),
  ],
),
floatingActionButton: ...
```

`container` doesn't have children property. If you want to show multi widget under each other you need to use `Column`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is entirely messed up. use the `column` up down the widgets and use `Row` for side by side the two widget

```
Column( 
   children: [
      const Text('닮은 꼴 찾기 '),
      Image.asset('assets/images/face_home_img_1.png'),
   ],
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!
I started to try flutter, so I was at a loss

Answer (score 0):

Your code structure is very wrong even though you can't have the flow like `container`->`child`->`children` you should not do it like this

The better way to optimize it is `container`->`child`->`Column` and Column will have children and then your code goes like this

```
Column(
  children: [
     const Text('닮은 꼴 찾기'),
     Image.asset('assets/images/face_home_img_1.png'),
  ],
),
```